# Forbidden Love: A tale of two kingdoms

Tags: story, chess

Once upon a time there were two kingdoms (bluex and pinksus) separated by a wall of eternal war. The kings of these two kingdoms each had one son and one daughter. Their children sought to end the war and unify the kingdoms.

The king of Bluex knew that his opponent cherished his son, while the king of Pinksus knew that the king of Bluex cherished his daughter. So one day, during a fierce battle, the kings both sent word to their forces to kidnap the other’s cherished child.

This resulted in both princesses residing in Pinksus and both princes residing in Bluex. The children realized that this was the perfect opportunity to unify the kingdoms so they gathered their knowledge and made their move.

They knew that the princes would have to rule their respective kingdoms and that they would have to be married to the princess from the opposing kingdom.

While the princes consulted each other, they discovered the exact battle plans of the kings. The rooks of Bluex always mirrored the movements made by the knights of Pinksus. This was just an annoyance strategy to prevent the king of Pinksus from making smart moves without sacrificing his own soldiers.

This meant that the princes would have to follow the same paths that the princesses would so they sent word to the princesses informing them of this.

The princesses now knowing how the forces would move, and knowing that the princes would match their every movement, devised a plan to unite with the princes without putting them in harms way.

Once united the princess of Pinksus would have to go home with the prince of Bluex and vice-versa all while staying out of harms way.

This was going to be tough, but they decided that it was best for both kingdoms and decided to go forward with their plans.

[image]

To clarify the rules:

- The rooks mirror the movements of the knights.
- For example, if you play `Ng8`, then the corresponding rook movement must be `Rg1`.
- The kings matches the movements of the queens.

  - The pink king matches the movement of the pink queen and vice-versa.
  - For example, if you play `BQc6` then the corresponding king movement must be `BKf3`.
  - To follow up and give another example, if your next move is `BQb6` then the corresponding king movement bust be `BKe3`.
- The kings must not be put in check (check by queen excluded).
- The wall of pawns and bishops cannot move but still impact check states and can be captured.
- The queen and king must be on the center two squares of the respective side.
- Blue king and pink queen on bottom, opposite on top.

Unify the kingdoms.

Please use algebraic notation, and denote the kings, queens, knights, and rooks, with a prefix of their respective color to prevent confusion in your answer. For example: `BQc6` would mean that the blue queen moved to c6. All other typical notation still applies, for example a capture `BQxc5` and a check `BRa1+`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to downvote this, because I tried to read through the wall of text, and still have absolutely no idea what I'm supposed to do. Are the Kings and Queens on the chess board the same as the Kings and Queens in the story, or did the princes(s) somehow get substituted? How can a king (on board) mirror a multi-square move of a queen?

Comment: @Bass The kings are the princes while the queens are the princesses. This puzzle is a form of [fairy chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess) and there are several examples of such puzzles here on the site. This is what allows us to define these particular movements. Also, I'm sorry if the story above made it confusing, I did that to add some flavor to the puzzle. The rules are clearly denoted at the bottom of the puzzle to ensure there is no confusion regarding potential moves. I hope this helps to win back your up-vote, but thanks for reading none the less.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies a lot. What about the rooks mirroring knights then, they move in completely different ways? Since they are placed below the knights, I assume they try to mirror the horizontal part of the knight's move, but what will they do if that move is blocked? And especially, which knight will they mirror after that? (I tried to redact my vote, but unfortunately it's locked now)

Comment: Take for example, if you play Ng8 then the corresponding rook would move Rg1. I'll update the post to clarify that further for it.

Comment: Um. Why on earth would you use **rooks** to represent blue pieces that move like **knights**?

Comment: It was to ease the story telling since I can make the pieces move however I'd like. It was easier to say the rooks mirror the movements of the knights instead of saying the knights mirror the movements of the knights.

Comment: I think I would like to question your judgement on that call :-) In any case, downvote redacted.

Comment: @Bass Well, in hind-sight, I could have just used knights on both sides as you pointed out. I'll remember that for future puzzles!

Comment: Does it matter who plays first? Bluex or Pinksus?

Comment: Also to match queen and kings movements (since same color must mirror each other movement) would the mirroring movement be in the same movement i.e. making same color movements in the or the following movement. like 1. PKb1, PQg8 or 1. PKb1, B___ 2. PQg8, B___?

Comment: In my humble opinion, this has very little to do with chess and should therefore not have the chess tag. Using chess pieces for a puzzle doesn't make it a chess puzzle.

Comment: @ITM This is simply an unofficial [chess variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess#Variants), as many other forms of fairy chess are. So, by definition, it has everything to do with chess. This puzzle simply includes a story because back when I wrote it I was trying to improve my storytelling capabilities.